# Tomcat serving wrong content type "text/html" for .svg resource

Tags: java, tomcat, svg

I configured my web.xml with

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

but when I fetch the resource, the content type in the response header is set to "text/html". Are there any conflicting factors that may be causing this behavior?

Comment: is the file extension of what you are serving end in .svg?

Comment: maybe the svg resource is not served by the default servlet?

Comment: @wero Actually I'm not using the default servlet. By default servlet do you mean the servlet with url-pattern="/"?  Or the DefaultServlet class provided by apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServletContext` has a method `String getMimeType(String file)` which provides a mapping between a file extension and a mime type string.

You can configure this mapping in the server configuration (e.g. in Tomcats `conf/web.xml`) or in the web application deployment descriptor.

The default servlet of the servlet container which is used to serve static content uses this mapping to set the content-type of a response (derived from the filename of the served resource).

Now if there is an application servlet which generates the response, the servlet **itself** is responsible to set the content-type.

Comment: Great, thorough answer.  This was definitely my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks correct. Tomcat will automatically create the content-type header based on the file extension using the mappings provided. Make sure the resource you are serving in fact has that file extension.

Comment: Yup I verified that the resource has .svg extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. We upgraded Tomcat version and after that `content-type` was equal to `text/html;charset=UTF-8` for whatever resources I tried to retrieve from the server.
Firstly I thought that there is some problem with `DefaultServlet` and `MIME` mapping configurations. But it turned out that starting from tomcat version 8.5.36

> The default Servlet should not override a previously set content-type.

https://oraweb.slac.stanford.edu/docs/changelog.html

And there was the following filter in our application that was applied to all endpoints:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Setting the character set for the request
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        // Setting the character set for the response
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        // pass the request on
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Therefore tomcat couldn't override `content-type`