# Amcharts images "304 Not Modified" error

Tags: javascript, linux, path, amcharts

I'm getting **304 error** when *AMCHARTS* images are requested to load.

Odd thing is that it works locally on my PC but doesn't work in development environment.

- Checked folder and files permissions > Permissions are all OK
- Checked PATH > Path is OK
- Tried absolute paths > Still not working in dev env, yes in my pc

Among trivial things I've done just to be sure, I've tried setting in amcharts config another **img/** path (one that I'm currently using WO problems) with *same* files and it keeps failing.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.

Comment: Open your site using Chrome....press F12 and select the Network tab, reload your site, check an image request and check if the path is right....you can also check(assuming that you are using apache) your server log activity, opening a terminal with the following command: `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log` and reload your browser and check the terminal output....

Comment: @Hackerman thanks for your reply. Tomcat's logs shows no errors related to this. Chrome shows correct paths but broken link images are displayed. Makes me go crazy.

Comment: So chrome show the right path, in the network tab, are you sure...you can click on a broken image and select open in a new tab....can you post the result of that test.....

Comment: Could it be the SVG driver? I believe is not able to find a way to render the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the images served with the correct mimetype? SVG should be served as image/svg+xml. Since you mentioned Tomcat [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724697/tomcat-serving-wrong-content-type-text-html-for-svg-resource) might be relevant.

You can also try using PNG images instead by setting [`svgIcons`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#svgIcons) to false in your `makeChart` call to see if that works:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  svgIcons: false,
  // other config omitted
});
```

Comment: You were totally right. Just setting svgIcons: false did the trick. Thanks for the time to answer and research.

Comment: Happened once again and arrived here to remember what to do!